# read-only in importing function running unit test in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, jestjs

I tried to mock an async function in Jest, I used mockResolvedValue as shown in the documentation. But I'm stuck with read-only issue where my mock function is imported from somewhere else, my code as below:

```
//index.js 
async function getUser(id) { 
    const user = await axios.get('./user') 
    return user
}
module.exports = {
    getUser
}
```

```
//index.spec.js
import { getUser } from './index.js';

it('test getUser', async () => {
    const expectedUser = [
        {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Alice',
        },
    ];

    getUser = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(expectedResult); //error of getUser is read-only
    const result = await getUser();
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
})
```

Comment: That test seems pointless, you seem to be trying to mock the thing that you're supposed to test, so you would end up testing the mock. Also you don't `jest.mock` anything, you should have a look at e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks.html.

Comment: I'm trying to test getUser function, isn't it right? but I don't want to hit the server directly, that's my goal.

Comment: Then you need to mock *`axios`*, not the whole of `getUser`. You could also look into e.g. `jest-mock-axios`. But Axios is an interface you don't own, so it's generally best *not* to mock it - consider having a facade around it, to isolate your code from changes to Axios, then mock the facade. Or if you have higher-level (e.g. end-to-end) tests that would tell you if the request stopped working, maybe don't test `getUser` at all.

Comment: I have this code: `async function getUser() { //what if there's multiple calls here? return something }` and shouldn't I test the result of getUser? axios is just a lib I use to get result from apis. I'm really confused now what should I do..

Comment: If `getUser` is more complicated that what you've shown, then it probably *should* be tested, and you either mock axios or extract a facade around axios and mock that (because, as you say, *"axios is just a lib I use"* - you don't own it, and might want to change it later). We can't make that judgement for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test the `getUser` function, you should mock the `axios.get` method and its returned value. Use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)
 method to mock `axios` module manually.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

async function getUser(id) {
  const user = await axios.get('./user');
  return user;
}
module.exports = {
  getUser,
};
```

`index.spec.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { getUser } from './';

jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return { get: jest.fn() };
});
describe('64385009', () => {
  it('test getUser', async () => {
    const expectedUser = [{ id: '1', name: 'Alice' }];
    axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(expectedUser);
    const result = await getUser();
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedUser);
    expect(axios.get).toBeCalledWith('./user');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64385009/index.spec.js
  ✓ test getUser (6ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.27s, estimated 12s
```

Comment: yes but within getUser function I also have few function after the axios call, to transform the data. And what if I'm not using axios? says it's a twitter wrapper lib, should I mock the wrapper lib?

Comment: @Ambrose For unit testing, you should mock each side-effected method/function to make your tests isolated. For pure method/function, you don't need to mock them generally unless the logic of these pure methods/functions are too complex, you just want to get a simply returned value.